# Is there a way to improve S6 audio quality?

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I just got a Samsung Galaxy S6 (Android 5.1.1) and I'm disappointed by the poor audio quality, as sounds are "chirping" and metallic, quite disagreeable to the ear. At first I thought it was just me, then I found [several comments of people having the same opinion](http://www.head-fi.org/t/759025/samsung-galaxy-s6-s6-edge-sound-quality).

Is there a way to improve sound quality? For instance a built-in permanent equalizer, firmware updates, etc. ?

Comment: Get a custom kernel that has SELinux set to *Permissive*, install Viper4Android and after that Dolby Atmos. You are technically unable to have bad sound from there on. Configure both to your needs and enjoy the best sound your device can output. (I have an S6 Edge and using those mods improved the sound so much, that I can't listen to music without them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happy to report that apparently the problem went away with the recent update to Android 6.0.1 pushed to the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you agree to void your warranty, your best bet would be to root your device and install a custom kernel, which can be further tweaked in order to improve the sound quality (amongst other things).

Comment: How exactly will tweaking your kernel *improve* sound quality?

Comment: After changing my kernel, I could mess up with the voltage of my speaker. That fixed up an issue in which I had a trembling audio output, so I guess it may work for the OP too.

Comment: That's a long shot imho just to get sound quality to improve. If its a known issue/bug, then probably will be fixed in next release by OEM. Sometimes, the issue might not be the kernel, as you suggest, but the medium of transport of the sound, like buggy bluetooth (software-wise).

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll leave my answer here as last choice, if there isn't a less dangerous method available.